# Parsing using HTMLParser

Tags: java

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
    parser.setInputHTML("d:/index.html");
    parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); 
    /*
    SimpleNodeIterator sNI=list.elements();
    while(sNI.hasMoreNodes()){
    System.out.println(sNI.nextNode().getText());}
    */
    NodeList trs = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("tr"),true);
    for(int i=0;i<trs.size();i++) {
        NodeList nodes = trs.elementAt(i).getChildren();
        NodeList tds  = nodes.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("td"),true);
    System.out.println(tds.toString());
```

I am not getting any output, eclipse shows javaw.exe terminated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  One tip - if you have a question, don't forget to ask it.  ;)  BTW - are you referring to [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) from SourceForge?

Comment: -1 please ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Pass the path to the resource into the constructor.

```
Parser parser = new Parser("index.html");
```

Parse and print all the divs on this page:

```
Parser parser = new Parser("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293729/parsing-using-htmlparser/");
parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null);
NodeList div = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("div"),true);
System.out.println(div.toString());
```

`parser.setInputHtml(String inputHtml)` doesn't do what you think it does. It treats `inputHtml` as the html input to the parser. You use the constructor to point the parser at an html resource (`file` or `URL`).

Example:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
parser.setInputHTML("<div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div>");
```

Comment: Works fine here. Let me post a complete example.